# Virtuals property on bson scheme

Tags: mongodb, go, struct, mgo

I always use [virtuals properties](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#virtuals) on documents with mongoose in my nodes projects, and want to use the same mechanism in my golang projects. I can't find the best way to implement something like this.

I have some struct, retrieved from my DB and want to add field based on my server config (like IP address, etc...). I want to avoid calling the same function every time I fetch this collection's documents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest would be to simply add a method to the struct which calculates the value you want, and when you need it, call that method.

For example:

```
type Person struct {
    FirstName string `bson:"firstName"`
    LastName  string `bson:"lastName"`
}

func (p *Person) Name() string {
    return p.FirstName + " " + p.LastName
}

func main() {
    p := &Person{FirstName: "Bob", LastName: "Archer"}
    fmt.Println(p.Name())
}
```

Advantage of this is that `Name()` will always return the "correct" name even if you modify the first or last name after retrieving the document.

If you want to avoid having to always calculate the result, you could store it in a field, e.g.:

```
type Person struct {
    FirstName string `bson:"firstName"`
    LastName  string `bson:"lastName"`
    name      string
}

func (p *Person) Name() string {
    if p.name == "" {
        p.name = p.FirstName + " " + p.LastName
    }
    return p.name
}
```

Note that when saving a value of `Person`, the `name` field would not get persisted as it is not exported.

And if you wan to automate this (e.g. you want the `name` to be calculated automatically when you fetch your documents from MongoDB), you can write your custom unmarshaling logic by implementing the [`bson.Setter`](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson#Setter) interface. The custom unmarshaling logic would be nothing special, just calculating and setting the `name` field after doing the default marshaling logic.

For example:

```
type Person struct {
    FirstName string `bson:"firstName"`
    LastName  string `bson:"lastName"`
    name      string
}

func (p *Person) SetBSON(raw bson.Raw) (err error) {
    type my Person
    if err = raw.Unmarshal((*my)(p)); err != nil {
        return
    }
    p.name = p.FirstName + " " + p.LastName
    return nil
}
```

And if you want the `name` field to be exported, e.g. `Name`, then you may use the `-` bson tag value to exclude this field from saving it to MongoDB, e.g.:

```
type Person struct {
    FirstName string `bson:"firstName"`
    LastName  string `bson:"lastName"`
    Name      string `bson:"-"`
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, it works and will save me a lot of work!